# Directing to Login Activity instead of main activity after signup?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Hello I'm using firebase auth for the registering and logging of user and I have a question on what to do? Because every time i click on the sign up button on my sign up activity it and it completes it. The activity goes onto the main activity instead of going back to the login activity.

```
btnSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //strinngs
            final String name = inputName.getText().toString().trim();
            String email = inputEmail.getText().toString().trim();
            String password = inputPassword.getText().toString().trim();
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter email address!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter password!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            if (password.length() < 6) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password too short, enter minimum 6 characters!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(name)){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter a name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            //create user
            auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(signup.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            Toast.makeText(signup.this, "createUserWithEmail:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                            // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                            // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                Toast.makeText(signup.this, "Authentication failed." + task.getException(),
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else {
                                finish();
                                onAuthSuccess(task.getResult().getUser());
                                String user_id = auth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class));




                            }
                        }

                        private void onAuthSuccess(FirebaseUser user) {
                            int type =1;
                            final String name = inputName.getText().toString().trim();
                            //newuser
                            writeNewUser(user.getUid(), name, type, user.getEmail());
                            startActivity(new Intent(signup.this, LoginActivity.class));
                            finish();

                        }
```

edit: thanks peter haddad. I got this code on my loginactivity `if (auth.getCurrentUser() != null) { 
startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, AdminActivity.class)); 
finish();`   thats why it automatically proceeds me into the main activity instead of login

Comment: Yes a new user  is getting added into the firebase console

Comment: inside method onAuthSucess write this Log.i("name", name); after `final String name = inputName.getText().toString().trim();` and see what you get in the logcat

Comment: http://prntscr.com/id4b02   What to check on the logcat sir?

Comment: You can also take a look [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bwgMWBhObDw&index=5&list=PLn2n4GESV0AmXOWOam729bC47v0d0Ohee) if you want. I have explained the entire authentication process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
else {
finish();
onAuthSuccess(task.getResult().getUser());
String user_id = auth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class));

 }
```

Remove the `finish()` above, as this destroys the activity and it may be going to the main activity after destroying this.

OP had this in the login activity under onCreate:

```
if (auth.getCurrentUser() != null) { 
startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, AdminActivity.class)); 
finish();
}
```

Therefore it was always immediately directing him to the AdminActivity. To solve this he had to remove it or/and add it under a widget instead.

Comment: that's admin activity

Comment: I mean when i clicked the register on the signup button it again goes to the admin activity or main activity instead of going to the login activity

Comment: @Yamiess remove this `writeNewUser(user.getUid(), name, type, user.getEmail());` to test it and try now

Comment: But i need that to add the data inputted on my database but okay

Comment: http://prntscr.com/id4fr1 still the same it still redirects me to the admin activity instead of login

Comment: Are u debugging again(it should work)? When you added this `Log.i("name: ", name);` did the name appear in the Logcat when u debugged? Did something like this `name: Yamiess` appear in the logcat @Yamiess?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/id4kn3 if you meant the one in the screenshot then yes it did got added but it just redirects me to the admin activitiy even though i coded it to redirect the user into the admin one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164912/discussion-between-peter-haddad-and-yamiess).